# Displaying Label Name and Value on Highcharts Pie Chart in R using Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I would like to display both the point name and percentage value on my highcharter pie chart in R. I managed to display the percentage value, but it replaced the name value instead of complementing it. Here's a code sample:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

df = tibble(
  id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  name = c('John','Kenneth','Aida','Ronda','Jasmine'),
  value = c(0.2,0.35,0.1,0.3,0.05)
)

df %>% 
  hchart('pie',
         hcaes(name, value))
```

Here I got the percentage values, but they replaced the name values:

```r
df %>% 
  hchart('pie',
         hcaes(name, value)) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(pie = list(
    dataLabels = list(
      enabled = TRUE,
      format = '{point.percentage:.1f} %'
    )
  ))
```

Any idea how to get both displayed. The values can be inside the pie slices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `{point.name}` to show the label like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

df %>% 
  hchart('pie',
         hcaes(name, value)) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(pie = list(
    dataLabels = list(
      enabled = TRUE,
      format = '{point.name} ({point.percentage:.1f} %)'
    )
  ))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>